# Jquery Ajax isnt Posting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Main">
        <script>
            $('#Main').load('text.txt');
            $.post('run.php','value=5');
        </script> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>

'run.php' code

<?php
  print_r($_POST);
  echo $_POST['value'];
?>
```

text.txt loads but there is no value being posted in run.php and the variable is undefined also could someone post a working code of the above as an example

Comment: Please go through http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: How do you know that no value is being posted? You don't look at the result anywhere in that code.

Comment: @Quentin He can see it with console log.

Comment: @R3tep — No. The console *can* be configured to show XMLHttpRequests, but AFAIK it only shows the URL so POST data wouldn't be visible.

Comment: @Quentin You can see the ajax call with post data and response with firebug.

Comment: @R3tep — That's possible, but there's no evidence the OP is doing that. My comment was aimed at finding out how the OP is determining that there is a problem (because it is entirely possible there isn't one and they just expect some DOM change to occur without specific code for it) not ways in which they could. As far as I can tell, this code should just work.

Answer (score -3):

Just write the page you want to post data on like:

```
$.post( "run.php", { id: "55", age: "24" } );
```

this will post data on run.php

or you can do it with load method like:

```
$('#Main').load('text.txt?id=55&age=24');
```

with GET Method.

Comment: "Just write the page"? You mean the URL? The code in the question already does that.

Comment: Putting it in the URL with a query string definitely won't work - the script (which is `run.php` not a plain text file) is reading from `$_POST`.